# Force SSRS 2008 to use SSRS 2005 CSV rendering

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, export-to-csv, ssrs-2008-r2

We are upgrading our report server from SSRS 2005 to SSRS 2008 R2.
I have an issue with CSV export rendering for SSRS 2008 where the SUM of columns are appearing on the right side of the detail values in 2008 instead of the left side like in 2005 as shown in the below blocks.
`117` and `131` are the sums of Column2 and Column3 respectively.

**SSRS 2005 CSV Output**

```
Column2_1,Column3_1,Column2,Column3
117,131,1,2
117,131,1,2
117,131,60,23
117,131,30,15
117,131,25,89
```

**SSRS 2008 CSV Output**

```
Column2,Column3,Column2_1,Column3_1
1,2,117,131
1,2,117,131
60,23,117,131
30,15,117,131
25,89,117,131
```

I understand that the [CSV renderer has gone through major changes in SSRS 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143380%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) with the support for charts and gauges and more importantly it provides 2 modes: the default `Excel` mode and `Compliant` mode. But neither mode helps fix this issue. The Compliant mode was supposed to be closest to that of 2005 but apparently it is not close enough for my case.

**My Question:**
Is there a way to force SSRS 2008 fall back a report to a backward compatibility mode so that it exports into a 2005 CSV format?

**Solution tried:**
*a) Using 2005-based CRIs*
Based on [this article on ExecutionLog2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2009/01/05/executionlog2-view.aspx), if SSRS 2008 R2 encounters a report whose auto-upgrade is not possible (e.g. reports that were built with 2005-based CustomReportItem controls), those particular reports will be processed with the old Yukon engine in a "transparent backwards-compatibility mode".

It seems like it falls back to its previous version mode (2005) and attempts to render it.
So I tried using a 2005-based barcode CustomReportItem and deployed to a SSRS 2008 R2 report server, but it shows the same result as before though it suppressed the barcode. This would be because SSRS 2008 R2 finds a way to suppress part of the report output and displays the rest. 
It would be great to find a 2005-based CRI that makes SSRS 2008 R2 process it with its old Yukon engine.
Please note that quite possibly, even if it uses the "old Yukon processing engine", it might still use the new CSV renderer hence it shows the same output. If that is true, then this option is moot.

*b) Using XML renderer*
We can use a custom XML renderer and then use XSLT to convert the xml to appropriate CSV but this would mean that we need to convert all our 200 reports. Hence this is not feasible.

Please note that we do not have the option of having SSRS 2005 and SSRS 2008 R2 deployed side by side.

Comment: What is the column order in the RDL itself, so that we can see how it relates to your csv exports?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the answer is: "No, there is no way to force the 2005 .CSV renderer to be used 2008R2." I expect the best answer for your problem would be to either keep a 2005 instance around, or rewrite the exports as SSIS packages. (SSIS is designed to have much more control over export formats.)

Comment: @dev_etter, the column order is Column2 and then Column3 with their totals near the footer.

Comment: @JamieF, looks that way. Thanks for your comment. Our last resort is to have SSRS 2005 and SSRS 2008 to co-exist and we redirect our CSV exports from our website to SSRS 2005 and the rest to SSRS 2008. (We select the type of export before we consume SSRS). SSIS would not be feasible now considering there would be a lot of rework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question triggered me to finally go out and try to [write a custom RenderingExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153624%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). The answer here would be to **create an extension that "wraps" the old SSRS 2005 CSV rendering extension** and makes it available under a new name in SSRS 2008.

I certainly think it's possible to do this. Unfortunately, I don't have the 2005 SSRS DLL's, so I did my proof of concept by creating an extension that wraps the *2008* CSV renderer. After quite a struggle I finally got this to work. Maybe this answer will help you in implementing this analogously for the 2005 CSV renderer.

A few notes up front:

- All kudo's should go to "[Broes](http://www.broes.nl/)", who wrote an excellent tutorial on his blog for a similar case on PDF watermarks ([part 1](http://www.broes.nl/2011/02/pdf-watermarkbackground-rendering-extension-for-ssrs-part-1/), [part 2](http://www.broes.nl/2011/02/pdf-watermark-background-rendering-extension-for-ssrs-part-2/)), which was invaluable in creating the extension.
- [Microsoft warns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154606.aspx) about writing an extension that *"Writing a custom rendering extension is difficult"*, and even though they're talking about an extension that actually *does* something (besides wrapping a default extension), I found just getting the thing to work can be quite a pain as well.

So here are the basic steps:

1. Create a **new class library** (.NET 3.5, not 4.0+) with a new class (see code below).
2. Add a **reference** to:

   1. Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering (for the default CSV renderer)
   2. Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces
   3. Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingCore
3. Create a **private instance of the CsvReport renderer**, initialize it in the constructor.
4. **Implement the IRenderingExtension** interface in your class. Route *all* method calls to the private instance of the wrapped renderer.
5. Edit the properties of the project to [sign it with a strong name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247123%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
6. **Compile**.
7. **Copy the DLL** to the ReportServer bin.
8. Edit the `rssrvpolicy.config` file to include your assembly [in a CodeGroup element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152828%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).
9. Edit the `rsreportserver.config` file [to include the extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154516%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).
10. **Reboot** the SSRS service.
11. (Optional) **Pray**, or light a candle.
12. Open a report in the report manager, and **verify** that your extension is there:

[image: Screenshot of the renderer]

Here's the code listing for the class that wraps the default CSV renderer:

```cs
using Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering;

namespace Ssrs2005CsvRenderingExtension
{
    public class Csv2005Renderer : IRenderingExtension
    {
        private IRenderingExtension oldskoolCsvRenderer;

        public Csv2005Renderer()
        {
            oldskoolCsvRenderer = new Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport();
        }

        public void GetRenderingResource(CreateAndRegisterStream createAndRegisterStreamCallback, 
                                         System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection deviceInfo)
        {
            oldskoolCsvRenderer.GetRenderingResource(createAndRegisterStreamCallback, deviceInfo);
        }

        public bool Render(Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.Report report,
                           System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection reportServerParameters, 
                           System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection deviceInfo, 
                           System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection clientCapabilities,
                           ref System.Collections.Hashtable renderProperties, 
                           CreateAndRegisterStream createAndRegisterStream)
        {
            return oldskoolCsvRenderer.Render(report, 
                                              reportServerParameters, 
                                              deviceInfo, 
                                              clientCapabilities, 
                                              ref renderProperties, 
                                              createAndRegisterStream);
        }

        public bool RenderStream(string streamName, 
                                 Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.Report report, 
                                 System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection reportServerParameters, 
                                 System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection deviceInfo, 
                                 System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection clientCapabilities, 
                                 ref System.Collections.Hashtable renderProperties, 
                                 CreateAndRegisterStream createAndRegisterStream)
        {
            return oldskoolCsvRenderer.RenderStream(streamName,
                                                    report,
                                                    reportServerParameters,
                                                    deviceInfo,
                                                    clientCapabilities,
                                                    ref renderProperties,
                                                    createAndRegisterStream);
        }

        public string LocalizedName
        {
            get { return "Oldskool CSV renderer"; }
        }

        public void SetConfiguration(string configuration)
        {
            oldskoolCsvRenderer.SetConfiguration(configuration);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the extension as added to the `rsreportserver.config`:

```xml
<Extension Name="OLDSKOOLCSV" Type="Ssrs2005CsvRenderingExtension.Csv2005Renderer,Ssrs2005CsvRenderingExtension"/>
```

And this is the configuration xml for `rssrvpolicy.config` as I used it:

```xml
<CodeGroup
        class="UnionCodeGroup"
        version="1"
        PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
        Name="OldskoolCsvGroup"
        Description="Code group for oldskool csv extension">
    <IMembershipCondition 
            class="UrlMembershipCondition"
            version="1"
            Url="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.SQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\Ssrs2005CsvRenderingExtension.dll"
    />
</CodeGroup>
```

One script that was very useful for quick testing if things worked (mainly because it involved a lot of trial and error), which I execute with the [RS Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162839%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

```vb
Public Sub Main()
    Dim items() As Extension
    items = rs.ListExtensions(1)

    For Each item As Extension In items
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name)
    Next item
End Sub
```

And that's it. At least it's all the important stuff I can still remember after a few hours of trial and error. To finish with one final note:

- The Application Event Log sometimes contains SSRS errors. One of them was "SSRS cannot load the ... extension". This was the last hurdle I cleared, and I cleared it by changing the target framework from **.NET 4.0 down to 3.5**.

Should anyone attempt this with the actual 2005 CSV rendering DLL: let us know whether it was succesful with a comment or an edit to the answer.

Comment: Very promising! Working on this as I am typing, will let you know.

Comment: After following the steps, I keep getting the `SSRS cannot load the ... extension` error in the event log even though I have the target framework set as 3.5. In my case, I had to register the 3 dlls of SSRS 2005 in the GAC because I cannot place them in the ReportServer bin directory (which already has the SSRS 2008 dlls of the same name)

Comment: Tried setting the target framework to 2.0 but it didn't help. I do keep getting a warning `The value for UrlRoot in RSReportServer.config is not valid. The default value will be used instead.`. Would this change the URL in the codegroup in some way?

Comment: Finally, got the error from the log file: `ERROR: Exception caught instantiating CSV2005 report server extension: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportRendering.IRenderingExtension' from assembly 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingCore, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'.` Apparently, my class is not referencing the SSRS2005 GAC'd ProcessingCore dll, instead it is going to the SSRS2008 ProcessingCore dll in the bin folder. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is happening because both versions (9.0.242.0 and 10.0.0.0) of 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces' assembly is in the GAC and hence it picked up the latest version. In fact the 9.0 dll has a cache type `Gac` and the 10.0 dll has a cahce type 'Zap' which is a sub-cache of Gac

Comment: Ooh, yeah, hadn't thought of the trouble with assembly versions and all that. Maybe a [BindingRedirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys.aspx) could help? If you figure it out, please feel free to edit your comments and findings into the answer.

Comment: Actually, this issue is more about the SSRS2008 Report Processor (`Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingCore`) not able to load the CSV custom renderer extension which derives from SSRS2005's `IRenderingExtension` (`Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportRendering.IRenderingExtension`)