# Configure SSRS to render reports on ITextSharp

Tags: reporting-services, itext

I want to render my reports to ITextSharp pdf library something similar to

[Force SSRS 2008 to use SSRS 2005 CSV rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902640/force-ssrs-2008-to-use-ssrs-2005-csv-rendering/13057837#13057837)

but on pdf rather than CSV.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: Won't [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/exporting-a-sql-server-reporting-services-2005-report-directly-to-pdf-or-excel) work?

Comment: pdf generated from SSRS don't support bookmark. I need bookmark navigation within PDF.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You've linked to another related solution, have you tried converting the CSV renderer to a PDF renderer or are you looking for us to do that for you?